# Why ASP.Net MVC Session value is null in controller ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller

I have a controller that called "Login"

this method is in Login

```
public bool IsAuthenticated()
        {
            if (Session != null && Session["UserRole"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I set session values in Login other method.(ex: LogOn)

But in X Controller

```
public ActionsResult Index() {
    if(!login.IsAuthenticated()){
      return RedirectToAction("Index","Login");
    }
    return View();
}
```

in this method is null.

If I controll Session in Controller Methods,I think this isn't functional

```
public ActionsResult Index() {
      if (Session == null && Session["UserRole"] == null)
            {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index","Login");
            }          
    return View();
}
```

Note:I don't Use ASP.net MVC Membership API

Comment: I assume that in the X controller the `login` is a property or field initialized manually, right ? Regarding the last code sample - this sample works, right ?

Comment: show us your LogOn action where you set session value